# No tengo instalado tkinter en Python, ni puedo instalarlo

Tags: python, tkinter

Un saludo.

Estoy ejecutando Python 3.10.2 sobre Windows 11 (instalación nativa, sin Anaconda). Necesito hacer una interfaz gráfica, el problema es que no tengo instalado `tkinter`, aunque supuestamente debe venir por defecto:

> Tkinter (and, since Python 3.1, ttk, the interface to the newer themed widgets) is included in the Python standard library. We highly recommend installing Python using the standard binary distributions from python.org. These will automatically install Tcl/Tk, which of course, is needed by Tkinter.

Tanto `PySimpleGUI` como `ntk` requieren de este paquete, luego no puedo usarlos. He probado prácticamente todo lo que se indica en este hilo (adaptando las instrucciones a mi SO y versión de Python): [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

Actualmente tengo instalados estos paquetes:

```
C:\Users\Pablo>pip list
Package       Version
------------- --------
autopep8      1.6.0
imutils       0.5.4
ntk           1.1.3
numpy         1.22.2
opencv-python 4.5.5.62
pip           21.2.4
pycodestyle   2.8.0
PySimpleGUI   4.57.0
setuptools    58.1.0
Tcl           0.2
tk            0.1.0
toml          0.10.2
```

Pero, si trato de importar la biblioteca, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
>>>
```

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo instalaste Python?

Comment: @padaleiana descargado desde su web oficial: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: En el instalador, ¿se te apareció algún check que dice _"tcl/tk and IDLE"_ como _Optional Feature_?

Comment: @padaleiana sí, pero no recuerdo si lo marqué o no. Error mío... es lo que quisiera solventar, porque sospecho que no marqué esa opción.

Comment: Probá ejecutar de nuevo el instalador: probablemente aparezca un botón que diga _Modify_ o en todo caso _Customize_, y a partir de ahí elegí lo que necesitás. Y si esa fue la solución, no olvides colocarlo como respuesta y aceptarla :)

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente se ha solucionado. Cómo no caí en algo tan simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución:

Hay que ejecutar de nuevo el instalador `.exe` con el que instalamos Python, y elegir la opción **modify**:

[image]

Luego, nos aseguramos de marcar la casilla **tcl/tk and IDLE**:

[image]

Hecho eso, dejamos las demás ventanas igual y esperamos a que finalice. Ya puedo importar `tkinter` sin problemas.

Agradecimiento a @padaleiana por la sugerencia.